# How can I use chemfig atom sep with aromatic rings?

Tags: chemfig

I'm using chemfig and I would like to set atom sep globally. However, it seems to disrupt aromatic rings:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig} 

\begin{document}
    \chemfig{**6(------)}
\end{document}
```

[image: example1]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig} 
\setchemfig{atom sep=1}

\begin{document}
    \chemfig{**6(------)}
\end{document}
```

[image: example2]

You can see the small ring in the lower left corner.

Is there a way to make rings work when atom sep is defined?

Comment: maybe atom sep=1em

Comment: That works. Thanks. But is there a way to put it as a multiple of the default value? I'm using atom sep=0.9, which nicely decreases atom sep by 10 %.

Comment: The default value seems to be 3em, so as a workaround I can set atom sep to 2.7em, and that produces the intended result.

Comment: @polyn Since nobody else seems to be replying, I will accept your suggestion if you post it as an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig} 
\setchemfig{atom sep=1em}
\begin{document}
    \chemfig{**6(------)}
    \qquad
    \chemfig[atom sep=2.7em]{**6(------)}
    \qquad
    \chemfig[atom sep=3em]{**6(------)}
\end{document}
```

[image]